# at what percentage of missing values we discard the variable(i have a variable with 21% missing values)?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have a variable with 21% missing values, is it okay to keep that variable or better to discard...
at what percentage of missing values we discard the variable..

Thank you

Comment: There is no such rule, and in any case, this is not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here. Questions on ML theory & methodology should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).